# Finding a specific Parameter according to a value

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to create a toggling system, where i'd have a bunch possible options and a value, i input all these possible options as parameters and then get the needed one. That's what i tried so far:

```
void Toggle(int scroll, int &state, int maxV, ...)
{
    state++;
    if (state >= maxV)
        state = 0;

    char *char_State = "";

    va_list argptr;

    va_start(argptr, maxV);

    for (int i = 0; i < maxV; i++)
    {
        if (i == state)
            char_State = va_arg(argptr, char*);
    }

    va_end(argptr);

    printf("State: %s\n", char_State);
}
```

i would use it like this:

```
int state = 0;

Toggle(0, state, 3, "Option 1", "Option 2", " Option 3");
printf("StateNum: %i\n", state);
Toggle(0, state, 3, "Option 1", "Option 2", " Option 3");
printf("StateNum: %i\n", state);
Toggle(0, state, 3, "Option 1", "Option 2", " Option 3");
printf("StateNum: %i\n", state);
Toggle(0, state, 3, "Option 1", "Option 2", " Option 3");
printf("StateNum: %i\n", state);
```

But for some reason when running the code from above i get this as an result:

```
State: Option 1  
StateNum: 1  
State: Option 1  
StateNum: 2  
State: Option 1  
StateNum: 0  
State: Option 1  
StateNum: 1
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong? Since this is my first time working with va any help is greatlxy appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`va_arg()` should be called for all 3 arguments every time you enter `toggle()`, or at least to every option until the correct one is found. That's because internally the va_list is just an array of data (pointers in your case) on the stack, and you must go over them with va_arg up to the required one.

```
void Toggle(int scroll, int &state, int maxV, ...)
{
    state++;
    if (state >= maxV)
        state = 0;

    char *char_State = "";

    va_list argptr;

    va_start(argptr, maxV);

    for (int i = 0; i < maxV; i++)
    {
        char* p = va_arg(argptr, char*);
        if (i == state)
            char_State = p;
    }

    va_end(argptr);

    printf("State: %s\n", char_State);
}
```